# Objc to swift bridge `use of undeclared identifier 'cocoarr'`

Tags: objective-c, swift, sttwitter

I'm combining Swift and Objective-C in the same project. I am trying to use **STTwitter** cocoapod like this:

```
// objective-c
// STTwitter category method
//
- (void)getStatusesLookupTweetIDs:(NSArray *)tweetIDs 
                     successBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *))successBlock 
                       errorBlock:(void (^)(NSError *))errorBlock {

    [self getStatusesLookupTweetIDs:tweetIDs
                    includeEntities:@(YES)
                           trimUser:@(YES)
                                map:@(YES)
                       successBlock:successBlock
                         errorBlock:errorBlock];
}
```

Swift Code

```
// swift
twitterApi.getStatusesLookupTweetIDs(ids, successBlock: { (tweets: [AnyObject]!) -> Void in
    process(tweets)
    finish()
}, errorBlock: { (err) -> Void in
    error(err)
})
```

Everything looks fine in Obj-C (I tried not investigate variable passed to `successBlock`, they all have valid values). But in Swift, when `successBlock` gets executed, `tweets` was:

```
Printing description of tweets:
([AnyObject]!) tweets = 1 value {
  [0] = <error: use of undeclared identifier 'cocoarr'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
>

}
```

How do I fix this and pass `NSArray` into Swift? (No compile error)

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me.

Instead of using:
`[AnyObject]`
 
try to use:
`[Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] (or whatever class is inside the array)`

Try to specify the type of the array instead AnyObject.

I hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Sorry the project has been long deleted. So no way to re-create. Could someone else confirm this for me?

Comment: Get this warning `cannot specialize non-generic type nsdictionary` when trying that code

Answer (score 0):

Try `[[String:AnyObject]]` rather than `[AnyObject]`

I got the same error in a smilar functionality. When changing from:

```
if let dictOrList = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:nil, error: &err) as? NSDictionary {
    callbackList = [dictOrList]
} else if let list = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:nil, error: &err) as? [AnyObject] {
    callbackList = list
}
```

to

```
if let dictOrList = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:nil, error: &err) as? [String: AnyObject] {
    callbackList = [dictOrList]
} else if let list = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:nil, error: &err) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
    callbackList = list
}
```

I got it working.